# How to connect Azure Web App to Azure SQL Database?

Tags: azure

I'm having what I hope is a simple problem.

I've published an API to an Azure Web App, which should fetch data from an Azure SQL database, but I'm getting a 500 error, which of course isn't helpful. Checking the logs in Azure doesn't give anything more useful to me.

I've added the connection string to the connection strings in the Web App. I have also created a method which returns the connection string from the repository class that's using it, so I know it's definitely seeing the correct connection string; so this means it's an issue connecting to the database with that connection string.

I have ensured that 'Allow access to Azure Services' is switched on, and when I use the query editor I can successfully pull data from the database.

I've also connected to the database using SQL management studio so I know the database can be reached.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As usual it turns out to be my stupidity, but I'll answer here in case it helps someone else...

I just updated my local app to use the Azure db connection string so I could get a more detailed error and it said the keyword was not supported 'initial catalog'.
This is when I realised that I developed this locally using Postgresql but couldn't justify the costs of that on Azure so switched to Sql Server but didn't change my connections to SqlConnection types!